# Using Type Parameters Created in One Class in a Different Class

Tags: java, generics, parameter-passing

I defined two type parameters, `T` and `G`, in one of my classes (`Table`). This `Table` class is using a `LinkedList`. I have made another class (`Node`) for the nodes of the `LinkedList` with a few setters and getters. I would like to use the same `T` and `G` in my `Table` class; which is making the `LinkedList` nodes. However, I am running into issues.

How do I use the same type parameters in a different class?

```
public class Table<T, G> {
        ...
}

public class Node {
   public T get(G g) {
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Node needs to declare the types too...

```
public class Table<T, G> {

    private List<Node<T, G>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
}

public class Node<T, G> {

    public T get(G g) { ... } 
}
```

Comment: When I do that and try to use my get() method, it says 'Cannot convert from Object to T)

Comment: Well, you need to share your code in order to get help about that. Specially the code around the line where the exception is being thrown.